# How to enable DEBUG logging in Spring XD?

Tags: spring-xd

I need to enable debug mode in spring-xd, how to do that ? 
I did not find any parameter in servers.yml defining debug mode.

Answer (score 4):

See `xd/config/xd-*-logback.groovy`

There are configs for singlenode, container and admin.

Comment: If the answer resolves your issue, click the check/tick mark below the up/down vote on the left. It will help other people when searching.